# Can you suggest me some good resource for learning Mathematica for physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I am into HEP. I know nothing in Mathematica and have to start from basics. HEP requires a lot of computation for Feynman diagrams etc could you please suggest some good resource to start learning Mathematica and some libraries that I would require?

Comment: There is a [Mathematica stackexchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Try sagemath, it's free and, in my opinion, superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll begin with tutorials

1) Mathematica's help documentation is more than sufficient for you and it contains detailed description of all the command and everything you need

2) www.wolfram.com/mathematica/‎ this is mathematicas official site where you will find loads of tutorials and video tutorials right from basics

3) check out blogs like http://www.sunnyguha.tk/?cat=6 which contain the basics of Mathematica.

Regarding the Packaged you'll need for HEP

1) Feyncalc

2) http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4580/

Hope you found it helpful